# Can an individual file a lawsuit in rem?

Tags: united-states, litigation, in-rem

Is there any case where an individual could file an in rem lawsuit (apparently suing a physical object, as in [*United States v. One Solid Gold Object in Form of a Rooster*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._One_Solid_Gold_Object_in_Form_of_a_Rooster), but with an individual as plaintiff)?

Comment: For in-rem cases, I prefer ["US vs. approximately 64k Pounds of Shark Fins"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Approximately_64,695_Pounds_of_Shark_Fins) - that was a real fishy case! Not in bad, but because sharks **are** fish! SD had the nerve [to sue 15 cats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Dakota_v._Fifteen_Impounded_Cats)... and [Pensylvania was sued **by** a car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_1958_Plymouth_Sedan_v._Pennsylvania) while [Kansas was sued by some books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantity_of_Books_v._Kansas)

Comment: Could one object sue another object?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "rem" but anybody can sue anybody for anything.

Comment: @Savage47 "in rem" is a Latin phrase meaning "about" or "against the thing". It refers to a government's jurisdiction over objects rather than persons. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_rem_jurisdiction

Comment: *United States v. One Solid Gold Object in Form of a Rooster*, *United States v. Approximately 64,695 Pounds of Shark Fins*, *South Dakota v. Fifteen Impounded Cats*, and *One 1958 Plymouth Sedan v. Pennsylvania* are "in rem" cases because either the plaintiff or (seemingly more commonly) the defendant was an object or animal (or a group of objects or animals) rather than a person. In all of those cases, the other party was either the US or a state; my question was asking if individuals can be parties to in rem cases (e.g. *John Doe v. Cell Phone* [I made that one up]), and the answer is...

Comment: ...yes, and it's apparently common in admiralty cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is common in admiralty cases, where a lawsuit will often be filed against a ship itself instead of or in addition to its owners. For instance, see [Vimar Seguros y Reaseguros, S. A. v. M/V Sky Reefer](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/515/528/). Quiet title actions can also be considered in rem, although that can depend on the jurisdiction and the type of action.

Comment: Also: [American Insurance Co vs. 365 Bales of Cotton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Insurance_Co._v._356_Bales_of_Cotton) - which wound up in SCOTUS and [Marcus v Search Warrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_v._Search_Warrant), which also ended in SCOTUS.

Comment: So in a quiet title case, that could happen if James Smith claims to be the rightful owner of John Doe's 1-acre piece of land, and John filed *John Doe v. One Acre of Land*?